# Knockout on Scroll Display a tables header (freeze-header like) with all bindings and dynamic components to work

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

Hello Fellows I have the following View Model:

```
function PeopleViewModel()
{

  var people=this;
  people.people=ko.observableArray([
    new Person({name:"John",surname:"Doe",gender:"Male"}),
    new Person({name:"Kurosaki",surname:"Ichigo",gender:"Male"}),
    new Person({name:"Luffy",surname:"Monkey D.",gender:"Male"}),
    new Person({name:"Inoue",surname:"Orihime",gender:"Female"}),
    ......
    new Person({name:"Gus",surname:"G",gender:"Male"}),
  ]);


  people.whatToSort=ko.observable('name')
  people.ascending=ko.observable(false);

  var sortFunc=function(a,b)
  {
    switch(people.whatToSort())
    {
      case 'name':
      a=a.name;
      b=b.name;

      case 'surname':
      default:
      a=a.surname;
      b=b.surname;
    }

    if(!people.ascending())//Swap if desceding
    {
      var temp=b;
      b=a;
      a=temp;
    }

    if(typeof a ==='undefined' || typeof b === 'undefined') return 0;
    return ( ( a() == b() ) ? 0 : ( ( a() > b() ) ? 1 : -1 ) );
  };

  people.sortSurname=function()
  {
    people.whatToSort('surname');
    people.ascending(!people.ascending());
  };

  people.sortName=function()
  {
    people.whatToSort('name');
    people.ascending(!people.ascending());
  }

  people.sortSurname=function()
  {
    people.whatToSort('surname');
    people.ascending(!people.ascending());
  };

  people.sortedPeople=ko.pureComputed(function()
  {
    return people.people().sort(sortFunc);
  })
}

function Person(data)
{
  var person=this;

  person.name=ko.observable(data.name);
  person.surname=ko.observable(data.surname);
  person.gender=ko.observable(data.gender)
}
```

And the following html displays them:

```
<table>
<thead>
<th data-bind="click:sortSurname">
  Surname
  <span >
    <!-- ko if:whatToSort() == 'surname'-->
      <i class="fa fa-caret-up" data-bind="visible:ascending"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down" data-bind="visible:!ascending()"></i>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko ifnot:whatToSort() == 'surname'-->
      <i class="fa fa-sort fa-pos-conf" ></i>
    <!-- /ko -->
  </span>
</th>
<th data-bind="click:sortName">
   Name
  <span >
    <!-- ko if:whatToSort() == 'name'-->
      <i class="fa fa-caret-up" data-bind="visible:ascending"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down" data-bind="visible:!ascending()"></i>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko ifnot:whatToSort() == 'name'-->
      <i class="fa fa-sort fa-pos-conf" ></i>
    <!-- /ko -->
  </span>
</th>

</thead>

<tbody data-bind="foreach:sortedData">
  <td data-bind="text:surname"></td>
  <td data-bind="text:name"></td>
  <td data-bind="text:genger"></td>
</tbody>
</table>
```

But because the data I display are too many I want to display the table's header with all bindings and   to work. When I scroll down the table after n scroll downs.

To be more specific, I want to do what libraries like http://plugins.jquery.com/freezeheader/ and many other similar libraries like https://laertejjunior.github.io/freezeheader/, but are useless when the html on thead section of the table is changed because of bindings, because the do not fetch dynamically the changed html.

To be more specific again, I want when I click on "Surname" to be able to sort again by surname and also to show the arrows for the sorted function.

Therefore somehow I need to rewrite the  section of the table on another div and with a custom binding to display it. Either by having a div with the same html html head's like:

```
<div style="z-index:99999999">
    <table>
    <thead>
    <th data-bind="click:sortSurname">
      Surname
      <span >
        <!-- ko if:whatToSort() == 'surname'-->
          <i class="fa fa-caret-up" data-bind="visible:ascending"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-caret-down" data-bind="visible:!ascending()"></i>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko ifnot:whatToSort() == 'surname'-->
          <i class="fa fa-sort fa-pos-conf" ></i>
        <!-- /ko -->
      </span>
    </th>
    <th data-bind="click:sortName">
       Name
      <span >
        <!-- ko if:whatToSort() == 'name'-->
          <i class="fa fa-caret-up" data-bind="visible:ascending"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-caret-down" data-bind="visible:!ascending()"></i>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko ifnot:whatToSort() == 'name'-->
          <i class="fa fa-sort fa-pos-conf" ></i>
        <!-- /ko -->
      </span>
    </th>

    </thead>
</table>
</div>
```

Or to use Templates. But still is not as DRY as I want.

What I want is to be able to pass a custom binding handler that copies the html dynamically to an another div and when it scrolls displays this div. Do you have an idea how to do that?

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24810084/html-table-with-fixed-header-and-fixed-leading-columns-with-knockout-controls-in ?

Comment: Nope but now that I see it it does not help me because I want something with more "Magick" similar on how  https://laertejjunior.github.io/freezeheader/ works.